# How to stop loop when I am opening workbook in vba

Tags: vba

My code is opening workbook in vba but when i cancel or doesn't want to open workbook, its not cancelling or closing. Here is my code can you guys please  give me any suggestion ...

```
    Dim shname As String
    Dim wb As String
    wb = Application.GetOpenFilename
      If wb <> "False" Then Workbooks.Open wb (this part is giving me prompt to open workbook)
      If wb = "False" Then workbooks.Cancel wb ( this part i want it to close the prompt when i click cancel instead of open....)
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured it out.... here is my code for future reference

```
          If workbookPath = "False" Then
        MsgBox "You chose ...."
           Exit sub
```

which will ext execution..

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, but you don't seem to understand it.

```
Dim wb As String
wb = Application.GetOpenFilename
If wb <> "False" Then Workbooks.Open wb '(this part is giving me prompt to open workbook)
```

> (this part is giving me prompt to open workbook)

No! `Application.GetOpenFilename` gives you the prompt.

However, this line is unnecessary (and won't work) so just remove it:

```
If wb = "False" Then workbooks.Cancel wb '( this part i want it to close the prompt when i click cancel instead of open....)
```

I would reorganise your code like this:

```
Dim workbookPath As String
workbookPath = Application.GetOpenFilename
If workbookPath = "False" Then
    'User clicked cancel. Do nothing.
    MsgBox "You chose not to open a workbook."
Else
    'User chose a workbook to open. Open it.
    Workbooks.Open workbookPath
End If
```